# How to avoid discontinuous path?

Tags: mathematical-modeling, operations-research, mixed-integer-programming

I have a mid-size two sided network, and am just trying to run a simple routing. $x_{i,j}^d$ takes a value of one if $d$ travel from $i$ to $j$. Each driver starts from origins $s_d$ and finishes at $e_d$. This is my simple routing:

$\sum_{j} x_{s_d,j}^d = 1 \qquad \forall d$

$\sum_{i} x_{i,e_d}^d = 1 \qquad \forall d$

$\sum_{i} x_{i,j}^d = \sum_{k} x_{j,k}^d  \qquad \forall d , \forall j \ne {s_d,e_d}$

The issue I'm facing is that my network is two sided (i.e. if we have $(i,j)$ then we do have $(j,i)$. And this cause an issue of seeing all routes ended up just exiting and entering origins and exiting and entering destination. This way the model actually satisfies all the above constraints without even actually traveling from $s_d$ to $e_d$. What's the issue? And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

To eliminate such 2-cycles, you can impose additional constraints $$x_{ij}^d+x_{ji}^d\le 1.$$ To eliminate longer subtours, look up *generalized subtour elimination constraints*.

Comment: Thanks @RobPratt do you know the reason why in most VRPs we don't see any  subtour and therefore subtour constraints but in my problem, we do see them? And what id if driver want to visit a middle node twice (entering node i then traveling from there again coming back to finish a job and from there to the destination? do you know an easy to understand resources that talk about generalized subtour elimination constraints?

Comment: The answer by @prubin suggests why such subtours are often naturally avoided because of the objective.  If you want to allow a driver to visit the same node multiple times, a common approach is to use a complete directed network, with the weight for arc $(i,j)$ equal to the shortest-path distance from $i$ to $j$ in the original network.  A good resource for GSECs is Section 9.5 of Wolsey's *Integer Programming* (1998).

Answer (score 1):

If the driver start node $s_d$ and end node $e_d$ are always different, then you can disallow entry into the start node ($x^d_{j,s_d}=0\ \forall j$) and exit from the end node ($x^d_{e_d, j}=0\ \forall j$).

If arcs have positive transit costs, and if you are minimizing cost, subtours should not be a problem (they would just add unnecessarily to costs).

Comment: Thank you both @prubin and RobPratt very informative!

Answer (score -1):

In general to avoid 2-sided network you can try something like
$x_{i,j}^d+ x_{j,i}^d = 0$
followed by your last flow balance/even degree constraint.

Comment: Your proposal would force all variables to be $0$, and that is not feasible.